# Changing SqlDataSource SelectCommand based on control parameters

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a web app using vb.net and SQL Server 2008 R2

In one of the aspx file, I have this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsParentUnit" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CN %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [t_Unit] WHERE ([UnitTypeID] = (@UnitTypeID) - 1) AND NOT [UnitTypeID] = 1 ORDER BY UnitName ASC"> 
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboUnitType" Name="UnitTypeID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

in which the datasource `dsParentUnit` will change based on selected value of a dropdown list `cboUnitType`.

The datasource `sdParentUnit` is used for another dropwdown list item.

Now, I want to change the `WHERE ([UnitTypeID] = (@UnitTypeID) - 1` so that it becomes something like this pseudo code:

```
If cboUnitType.SelectedValue <= 5 Then
   WHERE ([UnitTypeID] = (@UnitTypeID) - 1
Else
   WHERE ([UnitTypeID] = (@UnitTypeID) - 3
```

Can I do that?

And if possible, I would like to avoid building any stored function in the database, since the required paperwork for modifying database is really long...

Of course, only if it possible.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsParentUnit" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CN %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [t_Unit] WHERE ([UnitTypeID] = (@UnitTypeID) -     
     <%IIF (cboUnitType.SelectedValue <= 5, "1", "3")%>
     ) AND NOT [UnitTypeID] = 1 ORDER BY UnitName ASC"> 
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboUnitType" Name="UnitTypeID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```